# Configuring xsbt-web-plugin to open JMX and allow MBean inspection with JConsole/VisualVM

Tags: sbt, jmx, xsbt-web-plugin

How can I configure xsbt-web-plugin to open JMX port so I can inspect MBeans with Jconsole or VisualVM?

With my current setup VisualVM displays no MBean saying "the JMX connection could not be established".

I'm guessing the desired result would be xsbt-web-plugin invokes jetty in the lines of:

```
java
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 
-jar start.jar etc/jetty-jmx.xml etc/jetty.xml
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because xsbt-web-plugin does not fork a Java process when you run `container:start`, there's no way to use sbt's [`javaOptions`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Detailed-Topics/Forking.html#forked-jvm-options) to do this.  Instead, you'll have to instrument the sbt process itself to see any JMX info.

To do this, add the following line to your *~/.sbtconfig* file:

```
SBT_OPTS="$SBT_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099"
```